# Wistia Video keeps on loading in iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, video, video-streaming, wistia

I am using the wistia to render the video in mysite. I did it. The video is playing in all kind of devices, except **iPhone**(it keeps on loading). Can any one help to sort out this issue.

**My code:**

```
<script charset="ISO-8859-1" src="//fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script>

<div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_815evvnu4k" style="height:360px;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: What is the format of the video are you trying to play? I tried this code and it works fine in iPhone 
`
<script charset="ISO-8859-1" src="//fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script>

<div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_j38ihh83m5" style="height:349px;width:620px">&nbsp;</div>
`